# How can I make certain elements of a HTML document disabled depending on the signed in users roles?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a website for file veiwing for a small certain group of users, I have a login page, currently my website is hosted and authenticated using Firebase.

I am trying to make it so that when Person A logs in they can access Folder 1, folder 2 and the Admin console, but not Folders 3-8, but when person B logs in they can access folder 3, etc.

I can't think of any way to do this, I have searched google, however no joy!
I have no expected or actual results as I can't think of any way to do this, as a result of this I have no error messages.

I have attempted some things using divs for example and then using js for if user has this role then show this else dont

Currently this is what I have for testing different methods, if the user is logged in it should show the logged in div, else it should show the logged out div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D-Skinner - Welcome</title>

        <!-- Adds Firebase Things -->
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

        <!-- Adds the Auth Script-->
        <script src="/auth.js"></script>
        <style>
body {
text-align: center;

}
.Logged_In {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.Logged_Out {
    visibility: hidden;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    // If user is logged in
                    
                    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;


document.getElementById("Logged_In").style.visibility = "show"
                } else {

document.getElementById("Logged_Out").style.visibility = "show"

                }
            });
        </script>


<div id="Logged_Out">
    <h1>Please Login to D-Skinner Portal</h1>
    <p>We understand that you want access to Portal, but we need your username and password, otherwise we can't let you in, sorry!</p>
    <p>An alert has been sent to the D-Skinner team to alert them of this incident (just in case this was an accident), we will continue to monitor this IP Address and MAC Address for 1 hour to make sure that this isn't an attack.</p>
</div>

<div id="Logged_In">
    <h1>D-Skinner - Portal</h1>
    <p>We appreciate your beta testing, your login has been successful, please check with your beta co-ordinator to complete your beta.</p>
</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I will leave a temporary login at the bottom of this question for people to test (This login is valid until the 24th of October 2020)

Basically, the js fimd if the user is logged in, if so, what roles do they have, if they have certain roles show thenm certain div elements.

Current Login file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D-Skinner - Login</title>

        <!-- Adds Firebase Things -->
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

        <!-- Adds the Auth Script-->
        <script src="/auth.js"></script>
        <style>
body {
  background-image: url('assets/login_page_background.jpg');
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sign in</h1>


        <h4>Email address (required)</h4>
        <input placeholder="Email" type="email" id="fb_email"><br>


        <h4>Password (required)</h4>
        <input placeholder="Password" type="password" id="fb_password">

        <br>

        <button onclick="alert('Please contact support in order to get a password reset email \n support@d-skinner.com')" >I've forgotten my password</button>
       
        <br>
       
        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>

        <br>

        <button onclick="alert('If you are a teacher, your glow email address is your username, and your subject (in all lower-case) is your default password, you can reset your password from the settings page. Otherwise contact support. \nsupport@d-skinner.com')">Need A Portal Login?</button>
        <p>Only Portal users are allowed to access this service. If you do not have a Portal username and password then you may be committing an offence by trying to gain access to this service.</p>
        <br>
        
        <button onclick="window.location.href='info';" disabled>Find out more about Portal</button>
        </body>
</html>
```

Please ignore any errors in this page such as the 'Find out more about portal' button as I know it is not correct.

Auth.js Document:

```js
function login() {
    // Gets the value (Text Entered) into the input box.
    const email = document.getElementById("fb_email").value
    const password = document.getElementById("fb_password").value

    // Takes the values and attempts to log the user in.
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        console.warn("error.messsage\nerror.code")
    }).then(function() {
        after_login()
    })
}



function after_login(){
    // What happens when a user is logged in.
    
    window.location.href = "/D-skinner.html"
}
```

D-skinner.html document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D-Skinner - Welcome</title>

        <!-- Adds Firebase Things -->
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

        <!-- Adds the Auth Script-->
        <script src="/auth.js"></script>
        <style>
body {
text-align: center;

}
.Logged_In {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.Logged_Out {
    visibility: hidden;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    // If user is logged in
                    
                    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;


document.getElementById("Logged_In").style.visibility = "show"
                } else {

document.getElementById("Logged_Out").style.visibility = "show"

                }
            });
        </script>


<div id="Logged_Out">
    <h1>Please Login to D-Skinner Portal</h1>
    <p>We understand that you want access to Portal, but we need your username and password, otherwise we can't let you in, sorry!</p>
    <p>An alert has been sent to the D-Skinner team to alert them of this incident (just in case this was an accident), we will continue to monitor this IP Address and MAC Address for 1 hour to make sure that this isn't an attack.</p>
</div>

<div id="Logged_In">
    <h1>D-Skinner - Portal</h1>
    <p>We appreciate your beta testing, your login has been successful, please check with your beta co-ordinator to complete your beta.</p>
</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

**Login**
https://d-skinner.web.app/
Email/Username: help@stackoverflow.com
Password: Stackoverflow

Thanks for your help!

Comment: While you have documented the code you are using pretty well, it is not clear what the actual issue is!  You have the basic concept correct for a simple 'authorized/not' system (using separate divs that are visible or not) so what question do you need help with?  'Roles' is typically something you assign - which means you need to look that up somewhere else (database, etc.)  Then, you can do the same thing you are doing but with the role identifier "if(rolelookup === 1){ showrole1things }" sort of thing.  Identify the issue more clearly and you will get more direct help.

Comment: @CFPSupport I don't know how to make the Divs visible or not based on the roles I have assigned to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you are aware that everyone could access your hidden information.

If it is nothing secret you are good to go with client side implementation. But if it is some kind of sensitive data you are to implement you server side with all security and filtering.

So I would put authorization and user validation on the server. And frontend will just renders information from server.

[image: hidden information]

Comment: No private info, just to make things less confusing for the users.

Comment: In this case your idea is not bad. Also, you might look at some data binding library (such as knockout.js). It will allow you to have 1 boolean variable in you JS application and library will take care of showing/hiding related DIVs.

Comment: Thank you, however i got it usingf if  statements for roles within firebase.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you have everything you need (for the most part), you just need to add in the 'roles'......

You can do this a LOT of ways (typically I look at what the options are I'm working with and decide the best way for a particular project - I generally wind up using CLASS instead of ID - - personal preference and depends on what all is involved).  In your case, I have followed your code style (which is fine, though there are shorter ways to do things... - you will learn over time!)

So, reusing the body of your D-skinner.html only (the rest of the code doesn't affect this) you would have something like:

```
<body>
    <div id="Folder1" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <p>stuff for Folder 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Folder2" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <p>stuff for Folder 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Folder3" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <p>stuff for Folder 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="AdminConsole" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <p>stuff for Admin Console</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Logged_Out">
        <h1>Please Login to D-Skinner Portal</h1>
        <p>We understand that you want access to Portal, but we need your username and password, otherwise we can't let you in, sorry!</p>
        <p>An alert has been sent to the D-Skinner team to alert them of this incident (just in case this was an accident), we will continue to monitor this IP Address and MAC Address for 1 hour to make sure that this isn't an attack.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Logged_In">
        <h1>D-Skinner - Portal</h1>
        <p>We appreciate your beta testing, your login has been successful, please check with your beta co-ordinator to complete your beta.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                // you already know this, but here is a great way to test this
                console.log("user is now ", user);
                // now in your console (differs by browser - internet search to see how to open yours) you will see the user info in an object.
                // If user is logged in                    
                var displayName = user.displayName;
                var email = user.email;
                var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
                // here you can verify everything if you like.....
                console.log("displayName is ", displayName);
                // I'll only include this one -you can do others as needed
                document.getElementById("Logged_In").style.visibility = "show"
                // HERE YOU TEST AND DO 'ROLE' THINGS (same as you did 'user'...)
                // you did not include any way you are determining which role so I have to guess from the data you did provide.....                    
                if(displayName === 'Person A'){
                   console.log("displayName ", displayName, " MATCHED here");
                   // you can do all the 'what they can see' here
                   // (there are easier and better ways, but this is simple and follows your style of coding)
                   document.getElementById("Folder1").style.visibility = "show";
                   document.getElementById("Folder2").style.visibility = "show";
                   document.getElementById("AdminConsole").style.visibility = "show";
                }
                if(displayName === 'Person B'){
                   console.log("displayName ", displayName, " MATCHED here");
                   // you can do all the 'what they can see' here
                   document.getElementById("Folder3").style.visibility = "show";
                   // etc
                }
            } else {
                   console.log(" NO USER - showing Logged_Out div");                   document.getElementById("Logged_Out").style.visibility = "show"
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Again, you have the basic concept - you just need to follow it through with the roles (and since you never included HOW you assign the user and roles you will need to modify the example above to fit what you are doing).

Comment: Thank you so much, I assign the roles using code in my "Management console" which is controlled using a JS function in the auth.js file.

Comment: Sounds like this helped get things going then - that is great.  Please mark the answer as correct (unless something is missing - in which case, please give details on where you need help....)

Comment: All divs show no matter what, I changed display name to email address.

Comment: OOOPS!  I don't use standard JS and 'visibility' inline much (extremely rarely..) so I put 'none' not 'hidden' (one of the MANY tiny things in CSS and JS you have to get right....)  I updated the code (just changing the 'none' to 'hidden' should do it)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, seems a very easy mistake to make. :)

Comment: You are going to have to do some debugging on your end....  I can't see what you are typing, etc. (and stackoverflow isn't a "fix it for me" forum - it is for "help me figure out where to move next" sort of thing) - did you change the "displayName ===" line to match your user login???  Again, my code is only an EXAMPLE - you need to modify it to the environment you have and fit in secure data, etc.......  I will put in a couple of things so you can test (and then use similar things for anything else you need to test)

Comment: I also moved the divs to above the script - JS sometimes is funny about that too (again, you need to troubleshoot on your end for all stuff like this - every program tends to have 'gotcha' things like this in it that makes it too hard to duplicate/test in stackoverflow.  You can also do a 'chopped down' version of the code (no firebase - I don't want to log into your system....) and make  a codepen or other place to see this work

Comment: Taking your code to codepen I had to fix a LOT of things to make it work (your CSS was set to work on CLASS, though your JS was selecting by ID, etc.....)  see https://codepen.io/apps-n-add-ons/pen/bGepJdY to get WORKING code (pieces - you need to study why this works and yours doesn't - another thing is that 'visibility' doesn't use 'show' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility..... (all those little things....)  I would also recommend you use "display" instead of "visibility"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column in your `users` table called `role` and then test specific `role` to display or not your content.